# Unknown database error when connecting sql database to server (localhost)

Tags: php, database, server, xampp, localhost

What should I do to solve this error?

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown database 'testdb' in D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\project\connection.php:6 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\project\connection.php(6): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'root', '#Geoinformatici...', 'testdb') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\project\connection.php on line 6

**Code in Bracket IDE**

```php
<?PHP
    $server = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '#Geoinformaticionno1';
    $database = 'testdb';
    $connection = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database) or die("not connected");
    echo "connected"
?>
```

Let me know if any other thing is required to see to solve this error.

Comment: `Unknown database 'testdb'` It can't find the database testdb in your mysql installation. Double-check what databases are created.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to specify the server port in these brackets.

```
<?PHP
        $server = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '#Geoinformaticionno1';
        $database = 'testdb';
        $connection = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database, 3307) or die("not 
        connected");
        echo "connected"
        ?>
```

Comment: 3306 is the default port. If you have changed it, and haven't reflected the change in `php.ini` / `mysqli.default_port`, for sure you need to specify it for a new connection.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have not uploaded the database file in phpmyadmin. Create a sql file in the name you want to have the database copy paste the sql queries or import the file directly, refresh the page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

our local system or localhost has defualt user is `root` & password is `` that means blank.

if, you using add password from your end, for accessing phpmyadmin, then you can add your setted password. But, default, value user is: `root` & password is blank.

Comment: The error is: Unknown database 'testdb', that's mean could connect to server but can't read database, because it's not created or maybe is connecting to diff sql server (who knows).